# How to make a search helper for region filtering from a preselected country

Tags: abap

I have a selection screen like below code and I want to make a search helper to filter regions from selected value in P_LAND1:

```
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK B1.

PARAMETERS: P_LAND1 TYPE LAND1,
            P_BLAND TYPE BLAND.

SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK B1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpliest way is to reference the fields to the table-field, where they are maintained in SAP (keeping in mind that an input help is defined as well, but you can check it in SE11, not an issue in this case). For countries this will be table T005, for regions table T005S (pls. note the field is not regio, but bland):

```
PARAMETERS: p_land1 TYPE t005-land1,
            p_bland TYPE t005s-bland.
```

Also note, for the region by pressing F4 all possible values will be displayed, not just the regions of the country you entered one field above. If you need a user friendly solution, it has to be coded separately (in event `AT SELECTION-SCREEN on VALUE-REQUEST FOR ...`)

Comment: Thanks, edited question, but how would be the code for the user friendly solution? That's what I need specifically.

Comment: @Javerdds: you can start it here and come back, when you are stuck: http://www.saphub.com/selection-screen/dynamic-f4-help-based-on-the-values-of-other-field/

Comment: I'm stuck on the function call  `F4IF_INT_TABLE_VALUE_REQUEST` where I get the exception `CX_SY_DYN_CALL_ILLEGAL_TYPE`. Specifically the error is that the length under "FIELD_TAB" is incorrect but is the correct type.

Comment: Copy the code here... (may be open another question?)

Comment: Problem solved, I rewrote the code, did not know where was the problem but it works now, thanks.